# Trouble copying a config file in a multi-stage build with a wild card

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:alpine AS build
ARG stage
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
  apk add --no-cache bash git openssh build-base
ADD . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN go get -u golang.org/x/vgo
RUN vgo mod init && vgo mod vendor && vgo build -o service

FROM alpine
RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /src/${stage}-env.yml /app/
COPY --from=build /src/service /app/
RUN ls -la
ENTRYPOINT ./service
```

I'm passing in the `stage` argument in my docker-compose file, such as:

```
build:
      context: ./run-query
      args:
        stage: latest
```

But I'm not getting the correct output, the `${stage}` variable is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact

> FROM instructions support variables that are declared by any ARG
>   instructions that occur before the first FROM.
>
> An ARG declared before a FROM is outside of a build stage, so it can’t
>   be used in any instruction after a FROM. To use the default value of
>   an ARG declared before the first FROM use an ARG instruction without a
>   value inside of a build stage

You need to declare `ARG stage` again in the second stage

```
FROM alpine
ARG stage
```